# No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.ClientAuthenticationCache

Tags: hibernate, spring, spring-security

hi i faced below error in spring security application,i cant upload details company restricting big upload ,
 what is the problem?

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'accessConfirmationController': I
njection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Could not autowire method: public void o
rg.springframework.security.oauth.examples.sparklr.mvc.AccessConfirmationController.setAuthenticationCache(org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.Cli
entAuthenticationCache); nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.secu
rity.oauth2.provider.code.ClientAuthenticationCache] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. D
ependency annotations: {}:
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No matching bean of type [org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.code.ClientAuthenticatio
nCache] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your log , you should have a Class called `AccessConfirmationController` .It has an internal property whose type is `ClientAuthenticationCache`, right?

The error says you do not define any beans whose type is `ClientAuthenticationCache` , so the`AccessConfirmationController` bean cannot be created too.

You could use the Spring 's [component scanning feature](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-stereotype-annotations) to automatically  detect and instantiate the `ClientAuthenticationCache` .

To enable the component scanning feature , add `<context:component-scan base-package="some.package">`  in the `applicationContext.xml` .Any classes in the specified `base-package` and its sub-packages that are annotated  with @Component subtypes such as @Controller,@Repository, @Service  can automatically discovered and instantiated by Spring.

Comment: i delete Autowire above ClientAuthenticationCache ,i instantiated ,it resolved

Answer (score 0):

It means that you're trying to inject (probably through `@Autowired` annotation?) a bean of type `org.springframework.secu rity.oauth2.provider.code.ClientAuthenticationCache` but you have no such bean defined in your application.

Comment: how can i define ClientAuthenticationCache i ahve no idea,is there any way to define for using to be autowire  <bean id="accessConfirmationController" class="org.springframework.security.oauth.examples.sparklr.mvc.AccessConfirmationController">
  <property name="clientDetailsService" ref="clientDetails" />
 </bean>